# Visio protect object from selection

Tags: visio

A big problem for me creating diagrams in visio (and powerpoint and similar programs) is that if you have a background object, it blocks you from selecting multiple objects by lassoing. Instead you end up moving the background around, this is annoying.

In many applications there's an option to "lock" or "protect" a specific object so it becomes un-selectable while still visible on the drawing. In Visio there is no simple way of doing this as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

There's a rather convoluted way of doing this, it feels to me like Visio designers wanted to make this difficult on purpose. The methods I'm aware of I list here, feel free to let me know of a better way(s)

You can protect objects from selection by going to (hidden by default) Developer tab and pick "shape design"-> protection -> selection. However this does not actually protect them from selection, which makes sense . To actually protect the said object from selection, you have to open drawing explorer, which is also hidden by default and the visibility tickbox is in hidden by default Developer tab under show/hide section.

Drawing explorer, however won't highlight whatever object you have selected in the drawing, another unexplicable design decision. If you want to see the name of the object you've selected with live update, you have to enable the diagram navigation pane. That's found in View tab on Show section under "task panes" icon. This pane does highlight whatever you've selected and you can rename the object to give it a meaningful name, but not change the shape in any other way.

To finally protect that shape from selection, right click on the top level document on the drawing explorer and pick "Protect document" and tick "shapes" and hey presto, now your background rectangle is visible but not selectable. Very straightforward indeed

There are also layers which offer similar functionality but they naturally come with their own gotchas.

You can see layers on the Drawing explorer under foreground pages, page name, "Layers" tree. To move an object on a specific layer, you cannot do it by right clicking on the object, because of course you can't. There's an assign to layer button in Home->Editing->Layers->"Assign to Layer", which will let you select the layer(s) for the selected object. You can also do this by right clicking on an object from the Drawing explorer, but you have to know the object name, because there's no reverse selection .. The object name you can get from the Diagram navigation. By default "protected" and "lock" layers do nothing.

To change what the layers do, you again go to the Home -> Editing -> Layers and select "Layer properties". This is also available from Drawing explorer by right clicking on the "layers" tree under a specific page. Here you can control if the layer is visible and/or protected. However, if you lock a layer, you also cannot move objects to/from it, as that'd be too easy. So you have to untick "lock" if you want to move stuff in and out of a protection layer.

So there are two awkward ways of doing that that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

If the shape really is a background object then maybe you should be looking at putting the shape on a background page. You can then make it the background page for your active page. That'll fix all your shape selection problems.

Comment: It's a diagram of test equipment and the background box shows what items belong logically together inside the device enclosure. So it's not background-background as such. What I ended up doing is moving the object(s) to a layer which I make invisible. If I make the layer protected, the shape will interfere with snap operations although it's not selectable.